# Snowflake timestamp_ntz(9) to pandas datetime64[ns] conversion is wrong for future dates

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I read the timestamp column from Snowflake into pandas dataframe with the code below. It doesn’t correctly convert the big timestamp values (in the far future such as ‘2286-08-27 00:00:00.000’) into datetime64[ns] values. For example it converts ‘2286-08-27 00:00:00.000’ to ‘1702-02-06 00:25:26.290448384’ and stores the wrong value in python dataframe.
Does anybody know any solution to this problem with the snowflake connector?

```html
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector
snowflake_db_conn = snowflake.connector.connect(user=...)
cs =  snowflake_db_conn.cursor()
cur = cs.execute('SELECT * FROM TARGET.TESTTABLE;')
df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Snowflake code:

```html
CREATE TABLE TARGET.TESTTABLE
  (ID INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,
   StartDateTime TIMESTAMP_NTZ NULL);
   
INSERT INTO TARGET.TESTTABLE(StartDateTime) VALUES('2286-08-27 00:00:00.000'),('2022-11-19 00:00:00.000');
SELECT * FROM TARGET.TESTTABLE;
//ID    STARTDATETIME
//1 2286-08-27 00:00:00.000
//2 2022-11-19 00:00:00.000
```

Python Program output:

```html
(venv)>py test_snowflake_read_timestamp.py
   ID                 STARTDATETIME
0   1 1702-02-06 00:25:26.290448384
1   2 2022-11-19 00:00:00.000000000
ID                         int8
STARTDATETIME    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

My environment:

```html
#Python 3.9.12
asn1crypto==1.5.1
certifi==2022.6.15
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
cryptography==36.0.2
greenlet==1.1.2
idna==3.3
numpy==1.23.2
oscrypto==1.3.0
pandas==1.4.3
pyarrow==8.0.0
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodomex==3.15.0
PyJWT==2.4.0
pyodbc==4.0.34
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.2.1
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.28.1
six==1.16.0
snowflake-connector-python==2.7.11
SQLAlchemy==1.4.40
typing_extensions==4.3.0
urllib3==1.26.12
yamlordereddictloader==0.4.0
```

ps: I believe it has something to do with pyarrow as per [this issue](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/600) on github.

Comment: I have followed the snowflake installation instructions here: 
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html#reading-data-from-a-snowflake-database-to-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: It is interesting to note that the difference between those two timestamps, in nanoseconds, is 2**64.  There is an arithmetic overflow going on somewhere, where they're storing the computation in a 64-bit integer and it's overflowing.

Comment: I wrote an answer related to pandas.Timestamp.max, but I deleted it as I see the question is related to datetime64

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the snowflake.connector and `fetch_pandas_all()` method. These together return wrong dates if they are not within years 1677-2262 ([link](https://calmcode.io/til/pandas-timerange.html#:%7E:text=Since%20pandas%20represents%20timestamps%20in,limited%20to%20approximately%20584%20years.)).
Instead, use sqlalchemy and `read_sql`  as below.

```html
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine(URL(account =...))
connection = engine.connect()
try:
    df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM TARGET.TESTTABLE;', connection)
    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)
finally:
    connection.close()
    engine.dispose()
```

The output:

```html
(venv)>py test_snowflake_read_timestamp3.py
   id               startdatetime
0   6         2286-08-27 00:00:00
1   7         2022-11-19 00:00:00
2   8  2262-05-11 23:47:16.854775
id                int64
startdatetime    object
dtype: object
```